# Currency switcher not working for currency AED in Magento 2

Tags: currency, magento2.2.3, switcher

I have created a multi-currency website.
What I did to change Default USD to AED
1. Base Currency change to UAE Dirham
2. Default Display Currency set to UAE Dirham
3. Allowed Currencies also.
4. Currency Symbol set to AED.

The product price shows properly in AED and if i change to any other currency then switcher working properly.

[image: What i expected] [image: Currently showing]
expected result

Magento ver. 2.2.3

Comment: if i chose Euro + US Doller then " \Magento\Directory\Block\Currency" $block->getCurrencyCount() is 2 . but if i add one more (UAE Dirham ) then ther is no changes in count. similarly if i chose US and UAE then count is 1.

Answer (score 4):

Finally, issue solved. it was with currency rate.

Admin ==> Stores ==> Currency Rates

Flush Cache.

Comment: Yes, this was my case too. Thanks